# How to create an object with built-in "object()" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, built-in

I found there is [**object()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object) which is a built-in function in Python. *You can find [**object()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object) in [**Built-in Functions**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions)

And, the documentation says below:

> Return a new featureless object. object is a base for all classes. It
> has methods that are common to all instances of Python classes. This
> function does not accept any arguments.

As the documentation says, [**object()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object) can create an object but I don't know how to do it.

My questions:

- How to create an object with [**object()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object)?
- When to use [**object()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object)? or What are the use cases of [**object()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object)?

Comment: From my understanding, object doesn't have a very practical use for the programmer, but rather, it is a function which can create the default object. The attributes and methods of this object can't be altered, but all parent classes created are, in reality, child classes of this object. It contains all the built-in class properties. The syntax is just `my_obj = object()` and I don't think it takes any parameters.

Comment: `object` is not a function; it's the root of Python's class hierarchy. (The documentation isn't clear on that point.) (It's possible that once upon a very long time ago, it really was a factory function that returned an instance of the root type, but I don't think that's been true since new-style classes were introduced in Python 2.2.)

Answer (score 2):

To create an object with `object`, just call it: `object()`. However, it is never (as noted in the comments, it *may* be sometimes useful, when you need to have a something but you don't care what it is) used as is. `object` is just the (implicit in Python 3) base class of all classes. It provides basic features, such as allocation and magic methods, that you never directly manipulate in Python.

The naming follows one of Python's catchphrases "everything is an object".

Comment: I wouldn't say "never". Direct instances of `object` are useful as sentinels when `None` is not appropriate.

Comment: @chepner edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with only [**object()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object) as shown below:

```py
print(type(object()))
```

Then,the object of **`object` class** is created:

```
<class 'object'>
```

In addition, you can create and initialize the object of **`Person` class** with [**object()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object) as shown below:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

obj = object().__new__(Person) # Creates the object of "Person" class
print(type(obj))

obj.__init__("John") # Initializes the object of "Person" class
print(obj.name)
```

Then, the object of **`Person` class** is created and initialized:

```
<class '__main__.Person'>
John
```